# how to put more than one color into message text

Tags: c#, text, colors, messagebox

Is it possible to format text so there will be words in different color. For example if i need to format 'Text2' in Messagebox to red color:

```
Messagebox.Show("Text1" + "Text2" + "Text3");
```

Answer (score 5):

No, you will have to make your own form and your easiest path is to show a readonly RichTextBox on it with your messages.

For the richtextbox, you can create your own output like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"{\rtf1\ansi");
sb.Append(@"{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;}");
sb.Append(@"\cf1 This is black\par");
sb.Append(@"\cf2 This is red\par");
sb.Append(@"\cf3 This is blue\par");
sb.Append(@"\cf1 This is black again\par");
sb.Append(@"}");
rtb.Rtf = sb.ToString();
```